# I get an error while trying to read this dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I get this api response from coinbase

```
json_response = {"ask":"19540.18","bid":"19538.23","volume":"46199.99613583","trade_id":420452773,"price":"19539.07","size":"0.00091338","time":"2022-09-28T16:44:27.381482Z"}
```

and when i try to get the "ask" data by using

```
print(json_response["ask"])
```

i get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
print(json_response["ask"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I read on W3schools and this works for them.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you haven't yet parsed the response into a dictionary

Comment: Works fine when I copy the response you wrote and print it using your code. How do you request the data? Try to parse it directly to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is leading you towards the right approach:

> String indices must be integers

i.e, you are trying to index into a string, not a dictionary as you think. One way to approach this is by parsing the response **string** into a dictionary first:

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_response)
print(Type(data))
print(Type(json_response))

print(data['ask']) #should get you the expected result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API response is being stored in a dictionary of lists, instead of a pure dictionary itself.

(For examples on what this looks like, go here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-create-a-dictionary-of-lists/)

Hence the reason you are getting the error is because json_response can only be accessed using indices.

You need to convert your list of items into a dictionary first.
One way to do that:

```
    json_response = {"ask":"19540.18","bid":"19538.23","volume":"46199.99613583","trade_id":420452773,"price":"19539.07","size":"0.00091338","time":"2022-09-28T16:44:27.381482Z"}
    json_response_dict = dict()

    for key in json_response:
        json_response_dict[key] = json_response[key]
```

Then this code will appropriately convert the list into a useable dictionary and the following code:

```
    print(json_response_dict)
    print(json_response_dict["ask"])
```

Will work and print:

```
    {'ask': '19540.18', 'bid': '19538.23', 'volume': '46199.99613583', 'trade_id': 420452773, 'price': '19539.07', 'size': '0.00091338', 'time': '2022-09-28T16:44:27.381482Z'}
    19540.18
```

Comment: Nothing about the shared input suggests it's a list as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's a dictionary of lists, similar to what is described here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-create-a-dictionary-of-lists/

Comment: Except that syntactically, nothing indicates that. The input is in the format of {key1:val1, key2:val2 }

Your code loops over all the keys in the provided **dictionary** and uses that key to extract the value, all you've done is copy the values from one dictionary to another. Try printing json_response['ask'] on your example

Comment: The curly brackets of the initial provided json_response dictionary do indicate that.
Look here as an example:
https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

You can also copy the provided dictionary into your python console and this is what you get:

>>> json_response = {"ask":"19540.18","bid":"19538.23","volume":"46199.99613583","trade_id":420452773,"price":"19539.07","size":"0.00091338","time":"2022-09-28T16:44:27.381482Z"}
>>> 
>>> print(type(json_response))
<class 'dict'>

Comment: You are correct that my solution copies the dictionary of lists into a new dictionary.  Then accessing that new dictionary.